# How to make app views compatible with iPhone 6 and 6 plus

Tags: ios, ios7

I have XIB project ( news app ) so it's support ( iPhone 4 + 5 + 5s )

and I want to compatibility on iPhone 6 and 6 plus

So am create new file Xib and now I have 5 Xib files like this:

MainViewController.xib

MainViewController_568.xib

MainViewController_667.xib

MainViewController_736.xib

So when I want transfer from view to another by button I put this order :-

```
- (IBAction)MainViewController:(UIButton *)sender {
    MainViewController *YourApp = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    if (self.view.bounds.size.height >= 667)
        YourApp = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController_667" bundle:nil];
    else
    if (self.view.bounds.size.height >= 568)
        YourApp = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController_568" bundle:nil];
    else
        YourApp = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];

    //favController.parent = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:YourApp animated:NO];
    [YourApp release];
    //PP_RELEASE(YourApp);
}
```

but it doesn't respond.

Comment: Apple has provided autolayout use that

Answer (score -1):

Please use this code

```
- (IBAction)MainViewController:(UIButton *)sender {
MainViewController *YourApp = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
if (self.view.bounds.size.height == 736)
    YourApp = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController_736" bundle:nil];
else if (self.view.bounds.size.height == 667)
    YourApp = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController_667" bundle:nil];
else if (self.view.bounds.size.height == 568)
    YourApp = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController_568" bundle:nil];
else
    YourApp = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];

//favController.parent = self;
[self presentModalViewController:YourApp animated:NO];
[YourApp release];
//PP_RELEASE(YourApp);
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Try this code, it may help you

```
- (IBAction)MainViewController:(UIButton *)sender 
{
    MainViewController *YourApp = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    if ( [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 736)
        YourApp = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController_736" bundle:nil];
    else if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 667)
         YourApp = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController_667" bundle:nil];
    else if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)
         YourApp = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController_568" bundle:nil];
    else
         YourApp = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];

   //favController.parent = self;
  [self presentModalViewController:YourApp animated:NO];
  [YourApp release];
  //PP_RELEASE(YourApp);
}
```